# Case insensitivity in nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

We have several SEO pages like:

```
http://www.example.com/PageOne.html
```

Which we redirect in config like:

```
location = /PageOne.html {
  rewrite ^/(.*) /seo.php?id=1 last;
}
```

Problem is if a user access this page by typing:

```
http://www.example.com/pageone.html
```

"Page Not Found" error is displaying. There are approximate 500+ seo pages. How to write rule for nginx to ignore case sensitivity in url? I want a common solution for all url.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my issue. Sad to say that there is not many articles related to these issue, even nginx doesn't provide user friendly Help/Tutorials.

```
location ~* ^/-PageOne.html {
  rewrite ^ /seo.php?page_id=1 last;
}
```

Hope this helps!